# I want to automatically and randomly stitch / combine images as square tiles onto a DIN A4 canvas

Tags: cmyk, automation, imagemagick

Suppose I have a folder of different images, all different in sizes and resolutions.

I want to randomly choose between 6 and 18 of these images, scale, crop, and combine them as square tiles onto a rectangular (DIN A4) canvas. The end result should be a cmyk tiff or pdf file with a resolution of 1200 dpi.

Is there a way to do this with imagemagick or another tool?

The end result should look something like this [image]

but without the white margins between the tiles.

Comment: Yes its possible but it would help to pin the requirements if youd have a image that mocks up what you need. Anyway how do you guarantee that its 1200dpi?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Comment: @joojaa I've updated the question to include an example. I don't need the picture to guarantee a resolution of 1200dpi - that's just the setting for the output picture. The reason is that some of the original tiles will have a high resolution while others won't. But for my use case this doesn't matter. I just want them treated the same way - scaled up or whatever. And the final file must have 1200dpi.

Comment: @joojaa yes, I've seen montage. But I don't know how to randomize and automaticize it..

Comment: Randomaisation is not imagemagics job its the shells job that you are using. So what operating system and what shell do you use?

Comment: i use linux and gnome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73242/discussion-between-joojaa-and-bartholomaios).